# A GMAT algebra-precalculus question about ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

Ram committed two mistakes in an examination where all questions carried equal marks and obtained 72%. If he had attempted 4 more questions and made 3 mistakes, he would have obtained 84% marks. If there was no negative marking for wrong answers, how many questions were asked?

Comment: Why don't you say that it comes from this video  (youtube.com/watch?v=rn6EW4E1Xtc) ?

Answer (score 3):

Assume there are $x$ question in total.

Initially he answered $0.72x$ question correctly.

If he attempted $4$ more questions and made $3$ mistakes in total (the $3$ mistakes include the previous $2$ mistakes). That is he answered $3$ more questions correctly.

$$0.72x+3 = 0.84x$$

$$3=0.12x$$

$$x=\frac{3}{0.12}=25$$

I do agree that the phrasing of the question is a bit ambigious and can be improved.

Comment: It would have made sense if the question would have been 4 attempted and 1 mistake in total, right? @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: $1$ mistake out of the $4$ additional questions that he attempted.

Answer (score 0):

If he attempted 4 and made mistakes on 3, he answered one more correctly, so 1 correct = 12% marks. So there were $100/12\approx 8$ questions on the exam.

Comment: wrong, ans is 25 @Akababa

Comment: I don't understand the question either then